# WSO2 IS : Add new claim(field) of type checkbox to user profile

Tags: checkbox, wso2-identity-server

I'm using the latest version of WSO2 Identity Server 4.6.0. I'm adding some custom claim to the user profile. Is there a way to add a field of type checkbox ? where the user could able to check/uncheck.

I have tried setting checkedAttribute = true while creating the claim map through PS script. But, that didn't help either.

Looks like, only first time it renders as textbox. Once, I set the value as either true/false in WSO2 console it starts acting as checkbox. Is this the default behavior ?

All I need is, is there a way to set the default value for this field ? I did try through value property But, that doesn't seems to work.

Ravi

Answer (score 0):

Yes. True/ false values are treated as boolean values and displayed as a checkbox by default. Currently you cannot set a default value to a claim.

Comment: If I cannot set a default value to a claim. It won't display as a checkbox in first place.

Comment: How add add Custom created fields into User Profile or Available Claims for http://wso2.org/claims ? Please help... Thanks, Neha